# MongoRepository : how to throw an exception in findAllBy, if at least one value is not found in the repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application that uses a MongoDB repository to store some batch data. I need to update the batch documents via a bulk endpoint where I pass a list of objects as follows.

```js
[
 {
  "batchId": 1,
  "itemList": [
    {
      "inventory": 12,
      "purchasePrice": 20,
      "itemId": "1"
    },
    ...
  ]
 },
...
]
```

My update method works correctly and the content is simple as follows.

```
// batchIdList contains all batchIds extracted from the above list 
  
batchRepository.findAllById(batchIdList)
        .forEach(existingBatch -> {
            // update the existingBatch with new itemList data
        });
```

The batchRepository instance is extended from the MongoRepository<T, I> interface. And I have used the `findAllById` method here to find all matching batches in a single database query.

**Is there a way to throw an exception if any id of the batchIdList is not found in the batchRepository?**

(Given, one id, it can be achieved as follow.

```
Batch batch = batchRepository.findById(batchId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Batch not found"));
```

I do not need to loop the ids as it can cause heavy database queries.)

Comment: Inside the `.forEach` body, increment a variable counting the batches processed. After all batches are processed, check the count of batches processed equals the number of batches in the request.

Comment: So far I've tried a similar way that compares the length of retrieved batch size and batchId count. Thanks! 
I was hoping for a  cleaner way other than this.